# Make groupBy a key so that I can access in laravel blade?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.3

I have an array that I have merged into a collection. I have grouped the collection by Name. I wish to access this in the blade in the group. For example 
$result->name; $result->actuals; $result->forecast. 
The error I get is;

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$name

My collection in dd() is as:

```
  Collection {#464 
  #items: array:3 [
    "Peters Sow" => Collection {#459 
      #items: array:2 [
        0 => array:4 [
          "name" => "Peters Sow"
          "from" => "2017-06-01"
          "to" => "2017-06-30"
          "actuals" => 1
        ]
        1 => array:4 [
          "name" => "Peters Sow"
          "from" => "2017-06-01"
          "to" => "2017-06-30"
          "forecast" => 1
        ]
      ]
    }
    "Matthew Day" => Collection {#460 
      #items: array:1 [
        0 => array:4 [
          "name" => "Matthew Day"
          "from" => "2017-06-01"
          "to" => "2017-06-30"
          "actuals" => 1
        ]
      ]
    }
    "Marie Day" => Collection {#463 
      #items: array:1 [
        0 => array:4 [
          "name" => "Marie Day"
          "from" => "2017-06-01"
          "to" => "2017-06-30"
          "forecast" => 2
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created this in my controller using:

```
$merged = array_merge($a, $f);  
$grouped = collect($merged)->groupby('name');
```

And in my blade:

```
@foreach ($grouped as $result)
 <td>{{ $result->name }}</td>
 <td>{{ $result->actuals }}</td>
 <td>{{ $result->forecast }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You have nested collections. Try to flatten.

Comment: I tried flatten that seems to return a flat collection with 16 items.